# How to Print a form in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, printing

After searching around the web for about half an hour i've decided to ask for some help.
Currently i'm using this code:

```
procedure TViewSalesActivity.btnPrintClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TPrintDialog.Create(nil) do
  ViewSalesActivity.PrintScale:= 1.5
  try
   if Execute then
     ViewSalesActivity.Print;
 finally
   Free;
 end;
end;
```

To print a whole form.
The form includes buttons, text, captions and edit boxes etc.

The only problem is that the printout is to scale of the computer window; which is way too small. It is also stuck in the top left hand corner of the page. Is there any way to make it fill a whole page/ majority of the page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming which the `ViewSalesActivity` variable is a TForm descendant, try setting the [`PrintScale`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.PrintScale) property to `poPrintToFit`

```
 ViewSalesActivity.PrintScale:=poPrintToFit;
 ViewSalesActivity.Print;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i shall try that now.